# Manipulating a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, file, parsing, csv

```
import csv

reader=csv.reader(open('Names_Duplicates.csv', 'r'),delimiter=',')
writer=csv.writer(open('Names_NoDuplicates.csv', 'w'),delimiter=',')

Names=set()
for row in reader:
    if row[0] not in Names:
        writer.writerow(row)
        Names.add(row[0])
```

I am using this code to remove duplicates from a CSV file using Python 2.7(Windows). I am able to remove duplicates based on one column at a time. Is there anyway i can remove duplicates from multiple coloumn's at the same time?

Any help is appreciated.

P.S -- Pandas library is not working in my system.

Comment: Just a notice: you should open a csv output file in "wb" mode on windows if you use Python 2 to avoid lines ending in `\r\r\n`

Answer (score 2):

Use a tuple of multiple items as the key.

```
import operator
 ...
fieldmatches = set()
fieldspec = operator.itemgetter(0, 2, 3) # for example
for row in reader:
  if fieldspec(row) not in fieldmatches:
    writer.writerow(row)
    fieldmatches.add(fieldspec(row))
```